# How to power ten Raspberry Pi 3's?

Tags: pi-3, usb-power

Recently the company I work for has tasked me with a project, where we are purchasing 10 Raspberry Pi Model 3's to set them up for a lab within the office.

Can anyone suggest a power source for powering all the 10 Pi's from one location?

I have found [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YRYS4T4) from amazon but am quite unsure if it will suffice.

Comment: As long as it can safely supply the voltage and current required for a Pi through all the USB ports, it should be okay. I think personally I would be more comfortable using ten separate power plugs, and official Raspberry Pi power supplies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

10 Raspberry's will take up to 25 amps. This device will only supply up to 12A overall.

You can go either with two of these, or you can use an ATX PSU - these often can supply up to 30 amps and more on the 5V rail. The only issue is that you'd have to either connect a bank of 10 USB sockets to the PSU, or make 10 custom cables with micro USB plugs to plug them directly into PIs. That should be cheaper than getting two of these multi-port chargers, but will need a bit of tinkering.

Comment: Note that *modern* PC PSUs tend to have most of their power available on the 12 V rails. I just checked what a [fairly high-end 1200 W PSU](http://www.bequiet.com/en/powersupply/477) can supply: up to 25 A on the 5 V rail.

Comment: PSU specs aren't secret information, you can (and should) check them on the manufacturer's website, just to be sure. Not only when you plan on using them for powering devices other than PCs, but also when you are planning your PC build (because different components put load on different lines).

Answer (score 1):

Please take under consideration that powering your RPis from USB ports requires to know their power efficiency (in this case maximal current). For example using old USB charger may let RPi work, but as far You will start to add peripherals, power consumption will increase and Your Raspberry will shout down, what may damage Your data.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, on how these Pis should work together.

If they work together only loosely coupled, it might be the best to use a simple power strip and 10 independent usb chargers, each with at least 2.5A current (about 12W). If one of the chargers dies, only one of your Pis can't work on, but the other 9 will work happily as if nothing has happened. Redundancy is great with these.

If they are tightly coupled, you have no advantage using 10 independent chargers, because if one Pi stops working, the other 9 cannot do anything without it. With such a configuration (and may even be in general), I would recommend using a big 5V PSU with 125W or more (like this [beauty](https://www.reichelt.de/?ARTICLE=137111&PROVID=2257&wt_mc=amc141526782519998&ref=adwords_pla&gclid=CJym4PyXocMCFaXLtAodhhQASQ), but you can get them even much [much bigger](https://www.reichelt.de/Schaltnetzteile-groesser-500-W/MW-RSP-1500-5/3/index.html?ACTION=3&LA=2&ARTICLE=185844&GROUPID=7266&artnr=MW%20RSP-1500-5&SEARCH=%252A)) , and solder 10 USB charger cables to connect to the Pis. Such a 5V PSU is much easier to keep cool with a small fan, and big power adapters are usually much more robust than their little plugin counterparts. And cheaper as well, in terms of $/W.

I would not recommend a standard ATX PSU, because they need a consumer also on the 12V lines.